# Full-text searching in Contentful GraphQL API

Tags: graphql, contentful

Contentful’s HTTP API supports full-text searching through [this endpoint](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/references/content-delivery-api/#/reference/search-parameters/full-text-search-on-a-field), what's the equivalent using their GraphQL API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Contentful’s GraphQL API you can do searching within different fields with [collection filters](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/references/graphql/#/reference/collection-filters). Equivalent to full-text searching *on a specific field* is the ***contains* filter**.

Searching from all of the collection’s text fields or from multiple collections’ fields (as in [REST API's `&query=...`](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/references/content-delivery-api/#/reference/search-parameters/full-text-search)) with one filter isn’t yet possible, at least not to my knowledge. You would have to use specific filters for multiple fields with `OR` groups for that.

You didn’t give any example of your actual schema, so I’ll use Contentful’s [GraphQL demo space](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/tutorials/general/graphql/#demo-content) as an example.

Example for querying specific fields: to get all lesson copies with a text "data" in their copy, from a collection called `LessonCopyCollection`, do a query like this:

```
{
  lessonCopyCollection(where: {copy_contains: "data"}) {
    items {
      title
      copy
    }
  }
}
```

You can access the demo GraphiQL interface and test the query [here](https://graphql.contentful.com/content/v1/spaces/f8bqpb154z8p/explore?access_token=9d5de88248563ebc0d2ad688d0473f56fcd31c600e419d6c8962f6aed0150599).